# "Cannot find <arg" when passing argument to redux-saga with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-saga

I have a takeLatest() saga function, that calls a saga called postDeliverySubmitSaga(), which I want to pass arguments to.

I'm defining my functions like so:

```
export function* postDeliverySubmitSaga({
  payload: any
}: ReturnType<typeof setDeliverySubmit>) {
  console.log(payload);
}

export function* deliveryDataSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(setDeliverySubmit.toString(), postDeliverySubmitSaga);
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot find name 'payload'.  TS2304

    102 |   payload: any
    103 | }: ReturnType<typeof setDeliverySubmit>) {
  > 104 |   console.log(payload);
        |               ^
    105 | }
    106 |
    107 | export function* deliveryDataSaga() {
```

EDIT:

I have tried to define the saga like this. It compiles fine, but when I try to grab a member of the payload object (in this case, `payload.userToken`), it throws an error saying payload is of type `unknown`:

```
export function* postDeliverySubmitSaga({
  payload
}: ReturnType<typeof setDeliverySubmit>) {
  const userToken = payload.userToken;
  console.log(userToken);
}

Object is of type 'unknown'.  TS2571

    102 |   payload
    103 | }: ReturnType<typeof setDeliverySubmit>) {
  > 104 |   const userToken = payload.userToken;
        |                     ^
    105 |   console.log(userToken);
    106 | }
    107 |
```

EDIT 2:

If I do this:

```
export function* postDeliverySubmitSaga({
  payload
}: {
  payload: IDeliverySubmitData;
}) {
  console.log(payload);
}
```

Then I get the following compile error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ActionFunctionAny<Action<unknown>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TakeableChannel<unknown>'.
      Property 'take' is missing in type 'ActionFunctionAny<Action<unknown>>' but required in type 'TakeableChannel<unknown>'.  TS2769

    110 |
    111 | export function* deliveryDataSaga() {
  > 112 |   yield takeLatest(setDeliverySubmit, postDeliverySubmitSaga);
        |                    ^
    113 | }
    114 |
```

Comment: After edit you're showing error from another place `yield takeLatest(setDeliverySubmit, ...`

Answer (score 0):

That's because `payload` is [unpacked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) from the argument and assigned to variable called `any`.

Confusion between typing the argument vs destructuring with assigning new name.

---

Just remove `: any`

```
export function* postDeliverySubmitSaga({
  payload
}: ReturnType<typeof setDeliverySubmit>) {
  console.log(payload);
}
```

---

Not related, redux-saga is smart enough to identify `toString` on action creator, so watcher can be just: `yield takeLatest(setDeliverySubmit, postDeliverySubmitSaga);`

Comment: So i actually did what you suggest before, but when I try to call a member of the payload object, e.g. `payload.userToken`, it throws an error saying payload is of type 'unknown`.

Comment: This has something to do with `setDeliverySubmit` definition (and totally different question). If you're ok to use `any` as you tried before, you can go with `function* postDeliverySubmitSaga({ payload }: any)`. Or `({ payload }: { payload: { userToken: string } })`

Comment: You can open new question with the details on how `setDeliverySubmit` is defined, so we can try to understand why `ReturnType<typeof setDeliverySubmit>` is not working properly